# Manually invoke $q in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

From what I understand about `$q` in AngularJS it is run everything I refresh my page. This is similar to putting a function in `ng-init`.

Below is `my $q.all` code;

```
$q.all([$scope.getCart(), $scope.getCategory(), $scope.getMenu(), $scope.getRestaurant()]).then(function(data){
    $scope.cart = data[0].cart;
    $scope.cartItems = data[0].cartItems;
    $scope.delDay = data[0].delDay;
    $scope.delTime = data[0].delTime;
    $scope.cat = data[1];
    $scope.itemData = data[2];
    $scope.rest = data[3];
});
```

As you can see all the functions are called everytime I refresh a page and I get my data added to my `$scope`. This works as expected..

My question is how can I invoke `$q` through another function like below;

```
$scope.notEnoughTime = function () {
   if (year = 2015) {
    // invoke $q manually thereby calling 
    // all the functions and updating all the data in my scopes
   }
}
```

Comment: If by "refresh the page" you mean that the entire page is being reloaded, like clicking the "refresh icon" on the browser, then simply put you $q.all(..) inside a function, at the bottom of your controller (last thing) call that function, and then in your notEnoughTime you can just call the function again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Scott mentioned, you can put the call inside a function. With the request inside a function you can call the function whenever you'd like

```
var serverRequest = function() {
    $q.all()
}

$scope.notEnoughTime = function() {
   if (year = 2015) {
      serverRequest();
    }
}

// if you'd like the call the request when the controller is initialized you simple add the function call to your controller

serverRequest();
```